# How to solve GC_concurrent freed?

Tags: android, garbage-collection

```
07-06 10:33:28.405: DEBUG/dalvikvm(509): GC_CONCURRENT freed 4688K, 23% free 18428K/23751K, paused 7ms+19ms
07-06 10:33:29.484: DEBUG/dalvikvm(509): GC_CONCURRENT freed 24K, 14% free 20452K/23751K, paused 7ms+21ms
07-06 10:33:30.486: DEBUG/dalvikvm(509): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4623K, 26% free 17648K/23751K, paused 260ms
07-06 10:33:31.295: DEBUG/dalvikvm(509): GC_CONCURRENT freed 4K, 18% free 19692K/23751K, paused 6ms+19ms
07-06 10:33:32.335: DEBUG/dalvikvm(509): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 9% free 21739K/23751K, paused 7ms+24ms
07-06 10:33:33.334: DEBUG/dalvikvm(509): GC_CONCURRENT freed 4614K, 20% free 19206K/23943K, paused 6ms+18ms
07-06 10:33:34.345: DEBUG/dalvikvm(509): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 12% free 21254K/23943K, paused 7ms+26ms
07-06 10:33:35.245: DEBUG/dalvikvm(509): GC_CONCURRENT freed 4614K, 22% free 18687K/23943K, paused 6ms+17ms
07-06 10:33:36.275: DEBUG/dalvikvm(509): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 14% free 20735K/23943K, paused 7ms+22ms
07-06 10:33:37.234: DEBUG/dalvikvm(509): GC_CONCURRENT freed 4614K, 25% free 18169K/23943K, paused 7ms+15ms
07-06 10:33:38.374: DEBUG/dalvikvm(509): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 16% free 20217K/23943K, paused 6ms+28ms
07-06 10:33:39.547: DEBUG/dalvikvm(509): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 8% free 22258K/23943K, paused 8ms+30ms
07-06 10:33:40.545: DEBUG/dalvikvm(509): GC_CONCURRENT freed 4614K, 20% free 19718K/24455K, paused 6ms+19ms
07-06 10:33:41.595: DEBUG/dalvikvm(509): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 11% free 21766K/24455K, paused 7ms+24ms
07-06 10:33:42.575: DEBUG/dalvikvm(509): GC_CONCURRENT freed 4614K, 22% free 19199K/24455K, paused 7ms+19ms
07-06 10:33:43.814: DEBUG/dalvikvm(509): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 14% free 21247K/24455K, paused 7ms+36ms
07-06 10:33:44.725: DEBUG/dalvikvm(509): GC_CONCURRENT freed 4614K, 24% free 18681K/24455K, paused 7ms+17ms
07-06 10:33:45.724: DEBUG/dalvikvm(509): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 16% free 20729K/24455K, paused 7ms+23ms
07-06 10:33:46.654: DEBUG/dalvikvm(509): GC_CONCURRENT freed 4614K, 26% free 18162K/24455K, paused 7ms+12ms
07-06 10:33:47.746: DEBUG/dalvikvm(509): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 18% free 20210K/24455K, paused 23ms+21ms
07-06 10:33:48.917: DEBUG/dalvikvm(509): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 9% free 22258K/24455K, paused 6ms+29ms
07-06 10:33:49.924: DEBUG/dalvikvm(509): GC_CONCURRENT freed 4614K, 20% free 19691K/24455K, paused 7ms+20ms
07-06 10:33:51.164: DEBUG/dalvikvm(509): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 12% free 21739K/24455K, paused 13ms+24ms
07-06 10:33:52.174: DEBUG/dalvikvm(509): GC_CONCURRENT freed 4614K, 22% free 19172K/24455K, paused 6ms+18ms
07-06 10:33:53.255: DEBUG/dalvikvm(509): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 14% free 21220K/24455K, paused 6ms+26ms
07-06 10:33:54.234: DEBUG/dalvikvm(509): GC_CONCURRENT freed 4614K, 24% free 18654K/24455K, paused 7ms+17ms
07-06 10:33:55.324: DEBUG/dalvikvm(509): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 16% free 20701K/24455K, paused 6ms+22ms
07-06 10:33:56.184: DEBUG/dalvikvm(509): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4610K, 28% free 17648K/24455K, paused 242ms
07-06 10:33:57.025: DEBUG/dalvikvm(509): GC_CONCURRENT freed 4K, 20% free 19692K/24455K, paused 7ms+20ms
07-06 10:33:58.085: DEBUG/dalvikvm(509): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 12% free 21739K/24455K, paused 6ms+27ms
07-06 10:33:59.034: DEBUG/dalvikvm(509): GC_CONCURRENT freed 4614K, 22% free 19173K/24455K, paused 7ms+19ms
07-06 10:34:00.204: DEBUG/dalvikvm(509): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 14% free 21221K/24455K, paused 7ms+44ms
07-06 10:34:01.164: DEBUG/dalvikvm(509): GC_CONCURRENT freed 4614K, 24% free 18654K/24455K, paused 7ms+17ms
07-06 10:34:02.176: DEBUG/dalvikvm(509): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 16% free 20702K/24455K, paused 7ms+22ms
07-06 10:34:02.985: DEBUG/dalvikvm(509): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4610K, 28% free 17648K/24455K, paused 244ms
07-06 10:34:03.774: DEBUG/dalvikvm(509): GC_CONCURRENT freed 4K, 20% free 19692K/24455K, paused 7ms+20ms
07-06 10:34:04.813: DEBUG/dalvikvm(509): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 12% free 21739K/24455K, paused 6ms+28ms
```

Comment: wow.. You are asking for, how to stop garbage collection?

Comment: This is because using the map if i hide the map its ok but i need the map

Comment: But I believe that this is not going to affect your app in anyway.

Comment: It's unfortunate this question was closed. It is clear what is being asked, and it is an issue that developers face when working with certain types of views.

Comment: Completely agree with you dpk .

Answer (score 69):

Your heap is full

```
GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 14% free 21220K/24455K, paused 6ms+26ms
```

- `GC_CONCURRENT` : Jumps in because Heap is full
- `14% free 21220K/24455K` After this collection 14% of memory is free. Check the heap usage.
- `paused 6ms+26ms` Time taken to collect garbage.

Obviously there is a huge memory leak in your code that you have to fix.

Comment: the coding is for android 3.0 honeycomb and I am using the map in the code if i hide the map there is no such problem

Comment: I heard that this Maps problem is fixed in 3.1.Not sure.

Comment: +1 for such a useful information. I am also facing similar problem. I am using two linkedlists on GingerBird. see my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070189/android-audiotrack-message-obtainbuffer-track-0x1d1318-disabled-restarting

Comment: Is it common that the memory leakage is due to PNG images sometimes especially with the transparent ones? When making a game app, it happened to me, suddenly closes without an error message written in via Logcat.