# How to handle memory Leaks while continuous insertion in a LinkedList?

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have following function which is called continuously from run() of a Thread which is continuously running.

```
private LinkedList<short[]> playerData = new LinkedList<short[]>();

public synchronized void setPlayerData(short[] buffer) {
        // Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Inside setData..");
        playerData.addLast(buffer);
        if (playerData.size() > 10) {
            // Log.i(LOG_TAG, "playerData not empty");
            playerData.removeFirst();
        }
    }
```

Now **allocation Tracker** of DDMS says that a lot of objects are created inside addLast() (actually inside addLastImpl() ), So for that I would like to delete the arrays explicitly so that their is always enough memory in Heap. Now,

1. System.gc() option won't help because it will be called concurrently on every call to setPlayerData().
2. GC_CONCURRENT is eating all the CPU cycles, since app is very sensitive for time and even a few mili second delay is not acceptable.

For LogCat information please see the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070189/how-do-i-stop-gc-concurrent-running-so-frequently), which is my another question addressing the whole synarion. In this thread I am just trying to solve that bigger problem by dividing it in set of small problems.

**A possible solution** A possible solution could be to free the memory space explicity by deleting the arrays which are not required. But in Java how can we free an array created by the `new` operator ? i.e.

```
short[] buffer = new short[320];
// do some operation on buffer
/// now how can I explicitly free memory by deleting the buffer, when its job is over..
```

I know there is garbage collection to take care of all such things. But in my app **GC_CONCURRENT** eats up all the time. Other processes are starved due to this. It would have been great if I am able to explicitly free memory, i.e. delete in C++. You can see the LogCat information here...[A detailed question regarding my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070189/how-do-i-stop-gc-concurrent-running-so-frequently)

**EDIT 2**
3. Assign arrays to null

How that will help ? null arrays will be scheduled to Garbage Collection which I want to avoid since the method is called from a thread continuously (in every 20 ms). If I assign the array to null, GC_FOR_MALLOC messages will fill the LogCat...

Comment: It's hard to understand what exactly you are asking for. What is the problem? Why is the title asking for "an equivalent to the 'delete' operator in C++" if the question is really asking about reducing memory usage in your Android app?

Comment: @AlexLockwood: If there is something to free arrays I can delete the arrays not required.. To reduce the memory leaks..

Comment: I recommended you to just go through this link http://codelog.dexetra.com/getting-around-android-memory-blues

Comment: The only object allocated inside `addLast()` is an `Entry` object to hold the links and a reference to the array. That object will eventually be released to GC when you call `removeFirst()`. I doubt you have a genuine problem here.

Comment: @EJP removeFirst is only called when size > 10, and allocation Tracker is showing addLast() as I mentioned in the question. I doubt whether you read it completely or not...

Comment: @rahul Of course I did, and of course the allocation tracker is showing addLast() as you said because that's where all the allocations are happening. You also said the method is running continuously, so size will be > 10 rather quickly, and thereafter allocations will be matched by releases. No two ways about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem won't be solved by explicitly deleting objects ... basically because there is no way to do that in Java.

If you are *really* creating too much garbage for the CMS collector to cope with, then the only solution is to use an object pool to recycle the `buffer` objects instead of dropping them on the floor for the GC to deal with.  However, you need to be careful that you don't replace your current problem with others:

- The recycled objects may need to be "cleaned" (zeroed).
- A poorly designed object pool can be a memory leak.
- A poorly designed object pool can be a concurrency bottleneck.
- A poorly designed object pool can increase GC overheads, especially if you are running with a heap that is too small.

On the other hand, your real problem may be that your heap is too small for the application you are trying to run.  If you run too close to the limit, the GC won't reclaim much garbage each time.  Since the cost of running the GC is proportional to the amount of NON-garbage, it is easy to see that the GC's efficiency is non-linear as the heap gets closer to full.

Comment: +1, Thanks for such a nice answer... I will really go for Object pool... And I will surely remember your guide lines... Thank you sir..

Comment: @rahul - before you do that, it would be *wise* to check that the problem isn't really that the heap is simply too small.

Answer (score 4):

Simply set your objects to **NULL** after use and the *Garbage  Collector* will automatically take care of it. Practically Garbage Collector kicks in when your objects are not accessible by the code, so it destroys them to free up space.

Comment: can't you simply set your arrays to *null*?

Comment: How that will help ? null arrays will be scheduled to Garbage Collection which I want to avoid since the method is called from a thread continuously (in every 20 ms). If I assign the array to null, GC_FOR_MALLOC messages will fill the LogCat...

Comment: Define an array at global level and re-use it inside your code. Doing so will cause not to allot further memory and will keep the GC away.

Comment: I don't think you know how the garbage collector works. The GC doesn't 'practically kick in' when your objects are not accessible. I suggest you do some reading about the GC. There are a few things that trigger minor/major/full GC, but none of the events happen when an object is no longer accessible.

Answer (score 2):

Java does not have delete operator. The garbage collector destroys the object automatically when the code parts do not use them anymore.

That is when an object becames unreachable, the garbage collector destroy that object and free the memory related.

I read the edit, maybe you can solve your problem with a byte[] buffers pool. So the garbage collector does not need to garbage all the time the buffers.

private LinkedList playerData = new LinkedList();

```
public synchronized void setPlayerData(short[] buffer) {
  // Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Inside setData..");
  playerData.addLast(buffer);
  if (playerData.size() > 10) {
    // Log.i(LOG_TAG, "playerData not empty");
    byte[] buffer = playerData.removeFirst();
    // here return the buffer to the pool to reuse it
  }
```

}

Comment: that I know, Is there any thing we can do to explicitly free memory ?

Comment: assign a null value to the variable

Answer (score 1):

If you are having problems with the garbage collector the best thing is to allocate less new memory. One way of doing this is to use [object pools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern). Basically, reuse a buffer you no longer need instead of creating a new one.

Comment: I think my answer is still relevant. Don't use add, don't use remove, try to reuse what you have.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "equivalent" operator in Java. The system performs garbage collection in the background. No explicit method call will guarantee that memory will be freed immediately.