# Why waiting for rendering thread to finish in SurfaceView is usually guarded against interrupts?

Tags: java, android, concurrency, surfaceview, interrupted-exception

I've seen a couple of times the following pattern people use when working with `SurfaceView`:

```
while(true) {
    try {
        renderThread.join();
        break;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // retry
    }
}
```

For example, [here](http://code.google.com/p/beginning-android-games/source/browse/trunk/ch04-android-basics/src/com/badlogic/androidgames/SurfaceViewTest.java) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220572). Why do that? Especially given that nothing is actually interrupting the thread.

Comment: I think you can not be sure that your thread will not be interrupted in such multithreaded environment as Android. The meaning of the code is that the `SurfaceView` should always have a completed presentation, not mangled by unfinished drawing resulted from some external events (notifications, networking state changes etc).